# Trying to get property of non-object in Php+Mysqli+Html

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

I have an table with informations, with add edit delete view options, add, edit, delete, all are working fine, but view option having an error like trying to get property of non-object. I have called php code in html textbox to fetch data from database and it should display in a textbox, but inside textbox it shows error like above.

```
<div id="table-container">
             <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12">
           <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-sortable table-condensed  " cellspacing="0" width="100%"             
                           data-show-columns="true"
                           >               
            <tbody>

                <?php if(isset($result) && ($data_record) > 0)  : $i=1; ?>
                    <?php  while ($users = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>

                        <tr class="<?=$users->id?>_del">                            
                            <td><?=$i;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->zonee;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->location;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->pop_type;?></td>
                            <td><?=$users->switch_name;?></td>
                              <td><?=$users->switch_ip;?></td>
                              <td><?=$users->switch_make;?></td>
                              <td><?=$users->switch_serial;?></td>
                              <td><?=$users->switch_model;?></td>                               
                            <td> <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=<?=$users->latitude;?>,<?=$users->longitude;?>" target=\"_blank\"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0C8;</i></a></td>

                            <script>var page_<?php echo $users->id ?> = <?php echo json_encode($users);?></script>

                            <td><a data="<?php echo 'page_'.$users->id ?>" class="model_form btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>

                            <a data="<?php echo  $users->id ?>" title="Delete <?php echo $users->name;?>" class="tip delete_check btn btn-info btn-sm "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>                                  

                             <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" id="getUser" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <?php $i++; } ?>
            <?php else : echo '<tr><td colspan="8"><div align="center">-------No record found -----</div></td></tr>'; ?>
           <?php endif; ?>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
          <?php
              if(isset($_SESSION['flash_msg'])) :  
               $message = $_SESSION['flash_msg'];
               echo $error= '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> <strong>'.$message.'</strong> </div>';
               unset($_SESSION['flash_msg']);
              endif;
          ?>
</div>
      </div>

  </div>    
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.model_form',function(){
        $('#form_modal').modal({
          keyboard: false,
          show:true,
          backdrop:'static'
        });
        var data = eval($(this).attr('data'));
        $('#id').val(data.id);
          $('#zonee').val(data.zonee);
        $('#location').val(data.location);
        $('#pop_type').val(data.pop_type);
        $('#switch_name').val(data.switch_name);
        $('#switch_ip').val(data.switch_ip);
        $('#switch_make').val(data.switch_make);
        $('#switch_serial').val(data.switch_serial);
         $('#switch_model').val(data.switch_model);
         $('#latitude').val(data.latitude);
         $('#longitude').val(data.longitude);
        if(data.id!="")
            $('#pop_title').html('Edit');

        else 
            $('#pop_title').html('Add');
    });  
    $(document).on('click','.delete_check',function(){
      if(confirm("Are you sure to delete data")){
        var current_element = $(this);
        url = "add_edit.php";
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        data: {ct_id:$(current_element).attr('data')},
        success: function(data) { //location.reload(); 
          $('.'+$(current_element).attr('data')+'_del').animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        } 
      });
      }
     });     
});
</script>

<div id="view-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-dialog"> 
      <div class="modal-content"> 

         <div class="modal-header"> 
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> 
             <h4 class="modal-title">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> POP Information
             </h4> 
         </div> 

         <div class="modal-body with-padding"> 

             <div id="dynamic-content"> <!-- mysql data will load in table -->

             <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>zonee :</label>                      
                   <input type="text" name="zonee" id="zonee" value="<?php 
          echo $users->zonee;?>" class="form-control required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>                       
             </div>                                  
         </div>                
       <div class="modal-footer"> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
       </div>                    
      </div> 
   </div>
</div>

<!-- Form modal -->
  <div id="form_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify2"></i><span id="pop_title">ADD</span> POP INFORMATION</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Form inside modal -->
        <form method="post" action="add_edit.php" id="cat_form">
          <div class="modal-body with-padding">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>zonee :</label>
                   <input type="text" name="zonee" id="zonee"  class="form-control required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>location :</label>
                   <input type="text" name="location" id="location" class="form-control required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>               
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>pop_type :</label>
                   <input type="text" name="pop_type" id="pop_type" class="form-control required number">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="switch_name" id="switch_name" class="form-control required number">                       
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_ip :</label>
                   <input type="text"  name="switch_ip" id="switch_ip" class="form-control required" >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_make :</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="switch_make" id="switch_make" class="form-control required" >                       
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_serial :</label>
                  <input type="text"  name="switch_serial" id="switch_serial" class="form-control required" >

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>switch_model :</label>
                   <input type="text"  name="switch_model" id="switch_model" class="form-control required" >                     
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>Latitude:</label>
                   <input type="text"  name="latitude" id="latitude" class="form-control required" >

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <label>Longitude:</label>
                   <input type="text"  name="longitude" id="longitude" class="form-control required" >                     
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>                              
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <span id="add">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="id">
              <button type="submit" name="form_data" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- /form modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `var_dump()` to get to know what kind a type your code, variable or something else is.
Take a look at the [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to learn more about `var_dump()`
Check if you really have objects. In my expample, I have an array.
`var_dump($users);`

As well as you could go a much cleaner way in your `while` like that

```
<table>
    <tr>
        while ($users = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            // notice: you need to use double quotes to get
            // a variables value in echo
            echo "<td>{$users['key']['value']}</td>";
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) for object oriented style or procedural style to fetch.

Hope you can find a good way to structure your code as clean as possible.